# How to put instruction on how to take a selfie to ensure proper guidelines are met?

Tags: usability, user-centered-design, process

We are creating an app wherein a user needs to take a photo of their face and must be met with certain guidelines (e.g. must look in front, cannot tilt head to the side, etc.) The target audience is also the elderly.

What is the best way to guide them through this process? Any examples of this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option #1**

You can also use a bit of AR by detecting the face position and angle and communicating with symbols or wording if the picture is acceptable or not.

You probably have seen the Facebook and Snapchat dog, bear faces and various Halloween hats. At some point the AR effect disappears when your head is in a wrong angle or outside the desired area. So if you use the same type of effect with relevant icons that the photo is or isn't ok to take then this is another solution and no need for any how-to screens explaining something what can be adjusted on the go.

**Option #2**

Use a semi-transparent overlay when reflecting the direct camera view with an area in the middle where the head should be at. Please see the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that comes to mind is Airbnb! They did it so well. Showing example with animation and adding explanatory text. Take a look, I think it should work for you. https://airbnb.design/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/screens_2.gif

If not, I would suggest doing little video gif and not an animation to highlight multiple requirements.